# Problems displaying facebook share image using image parameter of share url

Tags: html, facebook

I am using the facebook share url but having trouble displaying the image parameter of the url, can anyone advise where I may be going wrong with this?

**HTML**

```
<a title="Share this on Facebook"
      href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?
      s=100
&p[url]='http://www.test.com'
      &p[images][0]='http://www.meandmrsjoneshotel.com/wp-content/themes/child-theme/img/fb-thumbs/home.png'
      &p[title]='This is the title'
      &p[summary]='This is the share description'"
      target="_blank" class="fb ir">
      Share this page on Facebook
      </a>​
```

**JS Fiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/pUMZb/

Thanks

Comment: Please use the Like button plugin (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) to share the proper way, afaik sharer.php has been retired.

Answer (score 0):

try to remove the apostrophes. Your code should be look like this

```
<a title="Share this on Facebook"
      href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?
      s=100
&p[url]='http://www.test.com'
      &p[images][0]=http://www.meandmrsjoneshotel.com/wp-content/themes/child-theme/img/fb-thumbs/home.png
      &p[title]='This is the title'
      &p[summary]='This is the share description'"
      target="_blank" class="fb ir">
      Share this page on Facebook
      </a>​
```